# Joomla 3.0 page goes to domain/index.php//

Tags: joomla3.0

I uploaded my joomla page via FTP to a server and I am having some route issues.

Insted of going to domain/index.php it goes to domain/index.php//

Solution?

Comment: Please try: System -> Global Configuration -> Search Engine Friendly Urls: No

Comment: in your .htaccess or web.config and let us know what the RewriteBase value is.

Comment: I find solution. In simple waether forecast module it was a some bug. Thank you anyway :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's a bad htaccess redirection interpretation... I've a similar problem with one of my current hosting provider.

Try to a search on google withe the following keywords : "your hoster name + joomla + redirect"

Comment: I didn' find anything useful. I think the problem is some directory in FTP -.-